# Passing PHP variables to Bash - more than one breaks it

Tags: php, bash, variables, curl

**Server 1 : php script**

Server 1 sets the `$mp3file` variable which is received by the bash script on Server 2 as `$1`

The php script calls ssh2_exec like this (minus all the connection info) :

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/root/incoming/test.sh ".escapeshellarg($mp3file)." &> /dev/null &");
```

**Server 2 : bash script**

test.sh (on server 2) contains a simple curl command :

```
curl -o /path/to/downloaded/file/$1 http://remotefilepath.com/$1
```

This all works perfectly, and the file is downloaded as expected.

But if I try to pass more than one variable like this :

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/root/incoming/test.sh ".escapeshellarg($mp3file)." ".escapeshellarg($artwork)." &> /dev/null &");
```

The file is only partially downloaded.

Am I setting multiple variables the wrong way here which is breaking the `&> /dev/null &` command?

Comment: What do the contents of `escapeshellarg($mp3file)` and `escapeshellarg($artwork)` look like? What does the final command string come out to before being invoked?

Comment: $mp3file = myfile.mp3 | $artwork = http://www.webaddress.com/file.jpg

SO is converting the artwork link into a clickable link but it's actually a full url to a jpg file

Sorry I don't understand the last part of your question?

Comment: So the full command you're sending to the server is `/root/incoming/test.sh myfile.mp3 webaddress.com/file.jpg &> /dev/null &`. That was the second part of my question. The next question I have is, which file is only partially downloaded? The mp3 or the jpg? Because your script is only downloading the first argument provided to it. It'll ignore the jpg altogether unless there's more to it than you've provided.

Comment: The mp3 file is the only file being downloaded at the moment. It works if I only send the $mp3file variable, but when I add more than one variable the download of the mp3 doesn't complete

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some messing around I found the only way I could get it working was by setting the escaped variables first :

```
$mp3file = escapeshellarg($mp3file);
$artwork = escapeshellarg($artwork);
$title = escapeshellarg($title);
$safeurl = escapeshellarg($safeurl);
```

Then passing them like this instead :

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/root/incoming/test.sh $mp3file $artwork $title $safeurl &> /dev/null &");
```

I'm not sure that this is the only (or correct) way to do it, but it works.